# How to check if user has installed the application using facebook deep linking?

Tags: ios, ios8, deep-linking

**scenario:**
when a user press on app invite , or ads on facebook application if the app not installed then the user will directed to appstore .

**what i need to know :** after opening my application i need to know which deep linking has directed the user to appstore .

**solution** i should use [deferred deep linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-).

but i didn't get any thing from facebook app, here is what i did:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 FBSDKAppLinkUtility.fetchDeferredAppLink { (url, error) in
            print("testDeferred Link , handler called");
            if error != nil{
                print("testDeferred Link , received error while fetching deferred deep linking" + error.description);
            }
            if url != nil{
                print("testDeferred Link , url:" + url.absoluteString);

            }

        }
```

alway the `url = nil` what may be the problem ?

here is the deep link headers:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="**********" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="*******" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="*****" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="********" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="********" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="*******" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="********" />
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="*******" />
<meta property="al:web:url"
    content="*******************" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
    content="***************" />
```

EDIT:
How do i test it :

1. open facebook app and press on app invite. then facebook app will direct me to the appstore.
2. after that i install the app using xcode.

Comment: What steps are you using to test?

Comment: @AlexBauer thank you for your comment, I've edited the question.

Comment: there are some known issues with deep linking and App Links. Is anything on [this page](https://dev.branch.io/features/facebook-ads/support/#testing-deep-linked-ads) applicable to your situation?